# Racket - most succinct way to do list comprehensions?

Tags: scheme, racket

I have some code that finds the most recently-modified file of a certain type in the current directory (see below). My question is: is there a more succinct, perhaps more idiomatic Racket, way of expressing this code? The idea is fairly simple: get all files of a certain type in the directory, and just pick the most recently-modified one out of them all. I tried a variant of `cwd-paths-of-type` using `for*/list`, and it seemed to be less readable. I feel like I'm missing something. Can anyone enlighten me?

```
#lang racket

(define FILETYPE ".pdf")

(define (cwd-paths-of-type filetype)
  (filter
    (lambda (p)
      (define filename (path->string p))
      (and
        (>= (string-length filename) 4)
        (string=?
          (substring filename (- (string-length filename) 4))
          filetype)))
    (directory-list)))

(define (last-mod-path paths)
  (define last-mod-time
    (apply
      max
      (map file-or-directory-modify-seconds paths)))
  (first
    (filter
      (lambda (p)
        (equal?
          (file-or-directory-modify-seconds p)
          last-mod-time))
      paths)))

(displayln
  (last-mod-path (cwd-paths-of-type FILETYPE)))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple Racket functions might help you here, [`filename-extension`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/More_Path_Utilities.html?q=filename-extension#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fpath..rkt%29._filename-extension%29%29) and [`argmax`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=argmax#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._argmax%29%29):

Note that the result of `filename-extension` is a [byte string](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/bytestrings.html?q=byte-#%28tech._byte._string%29), but it's easy to convert if you must use strings.

```
(define FILETYPE #"pdf")

(define (cwd-paths-of-type filetype)
  (filter
   (λ (p) 
     (define ext (filename-extension p))
     (and ext (bytes=? ext filetype)))
   (directory-list)))

(define (last-mod-path paths) (argmax file-or-directory-modify-seconds paths))

(displayln (last-mod-path (cwd-paths-of-type FILETYPE)))
```

Comment: `argmax` is what I was looking for, I guess! Thanks. `filename-extension` is helpful too. I was looking for a function named something like `filename-suffix`.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of writing last-mod-path, without using map and filter and apply, but an iterative approach. Without having to use those functions twice, that is.

```
(define (last-mod-path paths)
  (if (null? (cdr paths)) (car paths)
    (if (> (file-or-directory-modify-seconds (car paths)) 
           (file-or-directory-modify-seconds (last-mod-path (cdr paths))))
        (car paths)
        (last-mod-path (cdr paths)))))
```